# How to control ion-menu state from ngx store?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, ngrx, ngrx-store

I'm learning `ngx store` (I already know Redux) by looking at the [example app](https://github.com/ngrx/example-app/blob/master/src/app/containers/app.ts). There, they use the `<bc-sidenav>` component, and as you can see, it has a `open` binded attribute:

```html
<bc-sidenav [open]="showSidenav$ | async">
     <!-- ... -->
</bc-sidenav>
```

```js
showSidenav$: Observable<boolean>;

constructor(private store: Store<fromRoot.State>) {
    /**
    * Selectors can be applied with the `select` operator which passes the state
    * tree to the provided selector
    */
    this.showSidenav$ = this.store.select(fromRoot.getShowSidenav);
}
```

This allows to control the menu from the `ngx store` and do [cool stuff like that](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=11&v=70ojPxMA7Ig&t=249).

**Unfortunately**, the `<ion-menu>` does not have this `[open]` attribute. So, my question is **How do I code the same behaviour in Ionic ?**

**Several ideas :**

- Subscribing to the `showSidenav$` observer and trigger a `this.menu.setOpen(<showSidenav$ value>)` and dispatching an action accordingly. The thing is, I'm really not sure if it will work, do you think this will create the same behaviour that is in the video (cf. link cool stuff like that) ?
- [Add your ideas here by answering :)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it like that:

1. I get the ref of my menu and instantiate the boolean variable that will be injected in HTML:

   ```js
   @ViewChild('menu', { static: false }) menu: IonMenu;
   menuOpen = false;
   ```
2. In the constructor, I subscribe to my layout reducer and listen for changes

   ```js
   constructor(private menuController: MenuController, private store: Store<AppState>) {
       store.select('layout').subscribe((layout) => {
           if (layout === null || layout === undefined) { return; }
           this.menuOpen = layout.menuOpen;

       });
   }
   ```
3. I dispatch an action each time the menu is either opened or closed (ionWillOpen) and (ionWillClose) call those methods:

   ```js
   openMenu() {
       this.store.dispatch(new LayoutActions.OpenMenu());
   }

   closeMenu() {
       this.store.dispatch(new LayoutActions.CloseMenu());
   }
   ```